# Apposition of abstract nouns and concrete nouns

Tags: abstract-nouns, concrete-nouns

For example, ‘circle’ is a concrete noun and ‘circularness’ is an abstract noun. Though can a circle be circularness and circularness be a circle?

‘Circularness is a circle.’

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/circularness

Comment: ‘Circularness is a circle.’ doesn't make sense. Wiktionary is a crowd-souced unreliable dictionary.

Comment: _Circularity_ is a better word, but it means 'the fact of being circle-shaped', not 'a circle'.

Comment: Where have you apposed anything?? To appose means to put x right next to y. "John, my best friend, won a essay contest." John and my best friend are apposed to one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the word "circularness" in several online dictionaries other than Wiktionary, though it definitely isn't something I would use. *Circularity* (as suggested by Kate Bunting) sounds better, but I think **roundness** is more common.

When you say:

> A circle is circularness.

this is wrong. You need an *adjective* to describe the circle, not a noun. You should change this to

> A circle is **circular**.
>
> A circle is **round**.